# Node App builds locally but fails in GitlabCI

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have a svelte app that is built with SvelteKit. It runs fine locally and local Docker image, but it fails in the Gitlab CI.

This is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: node:16.15.0-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - lint
  - test

install:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd frontend/
    - npm ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/
  only:
    - merge_requests

format-and-lint:
  stage: lint
  needs: [install]
  script:
    - cd frontend/
    - npm run format
    - npm run lint
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/
  only:
    - merge_requests


# --------------- This step always fails ---------------
cypress:
  stage: test
  needs: [format-and-lint]
  script:
    - cd frontend/
    - npm run build
    - npm run preview
    - npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/lehrenden-eintragung/*"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/
  only: 
    - merge_requests
# -----------------------------------------------------

vitest:
  stage: test
  needs: [format-and-lint]
  script:
    - cd frontend/
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "bezeichnungLang": "llp-frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
        "build": "svelte-kit build",
        "package": "svelte-kit package",
        "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
        "prepare": "svelte-kit sync",
        "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --compiler-warnings \"css-unused-selector:ignore\"",
        "check:watch": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write --plugin-search-dir=. .",
        "test": "vitest run",
        "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0-next.40",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.323",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16",
        "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0",
        "@tsconfig/svelte": "^3.0",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.9",
        "@types/jest": "^27.4",
        "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1",
        "cypress": "^9.6.1",
        "eslint": "^8.14",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.4",
        "jsdom": "^19.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16",
        "prettier": "^2.6",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7",
        "purgecss-from-svelte": "^2.0",
        "simple-svelte-autocomplete": "^2.4.0",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5",
        "svelte": "^3.46",
        "svelte-check": "^2.4",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10",
        "ts-node": "^10.7",
        "ts-replace-all": "^1.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3",
        "typescript": "^4.6.4",
        "vitest": "^0.10",
        "vitest-svelte-kit": "^0.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ],
        "presets": [
            [
                "@babel/preset-env"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "since 2017-06"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "sass": "^1.52.2",
        "vite": "^2.9.9"
    }
}
```

The GitlabCI fails with the following error:

```
Using docker image sha256:e5065cc780745864eeee3280fe347b33e90961c98c7d3e14d5b660e16aef24ce for node:16.15.0-alpine with digest node@sha256:1a9a71ea86aad332aa7740316d4111ee1bd4e890df47d3b5eff3e5bded3b3d10 ...
$ cd frontend/
$ ls
convertTestData.js
cypress
cypress.json
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
setupTestEnvironment.ts
src
static
svelte.config.js
tsconfig.json
vite.config.ts
vitest.config.js
$ npm run build
> build
> svelte-kit build
8:59:30 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] hmr is enabled but compilerOptions.dev is false, forcing it to true
8:59:30 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] options.hot is enabled but does not work on production build, forcing it to false
8:59:30 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] you are building for production but compilerOptions.dev is true, forcing it to false
vite v2.9.12 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
[vite-plugin-svelte] /builds/llp/llp/frontend/src/routes/__layout.svelte:32:1 The keyword 'let' is reserved
file: /builds/llp/llp/frontend/src/routes/__layout.svelte:32:1
 30 |  
 31 |  function create_fragment(ctx) {
 32 |    let div3;
         ^
 33 |    let div2;
 34 |    let div0;
> /builds/llp/llp/frontend/src/routes/__layout.svelte:32:1 The keyword 'let' is reserved
    at error (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17716:19)
    at Parser$1.error (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17792:9)
    at Parser$1.acorn_error (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17786:14)
    at read_expression (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:8652:16)
    at mustache (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17475:28)
    at new Parser$1 (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17751:21)
    at parse$3 (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:17883:20)
    at compile (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:32265:17)
    at compileSvelte2 (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:351:20)
    at async Object.transform (file:///builds/llp/llp/frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:1791:25)
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

All other steps in the pipeline run fine and finish without error. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify an exact version of sveltejs/kit. The build fails on version 1.0.0-next.350 but runs fine with 1.0.0-next.323. Somehow, besides having the same node version, in the pipeline version 1.0.0-next.350 was installed.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly from `[vite-plugin-svelte]` which couldn't transform line 32 at __layout.svelte component.

```
function create_fragment(ctx) {
   let div3;
   ^
   let div2;
   let div0;
/builds/llp/llp/frontend/src/routes/__layout.svelte:32:1 The keyword 'let' is reserved
```

Try upgrade the following dependencies:

`@sveltejs/kit` (this has vite built-in, and doesn't need extra dependency)

`svelte` and related dependencies.